# iOS - Keeping a Core Data and Neo4j database in sync

Tags: ios, core-data, neo4j

I am designing an application for iPhone which uses a Neo4j back end. It seems like the biggest piece of work is going to be keeping both data stores in sync with each other. Does anyone have any experience in this problem? What did you do? Does/can anyone else recommend any tips or design solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I guess [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) could be a good approach to this. In short you basically record the actions being performed on a use case level as a sequence of events. These can be replayed during sync phase.

There also an excellent podcast on this: [being the worst](http://beingtheworst.com/2012/episode-4-event-sourcing-basics)

Comment: Apologies for the time to reply, for vice versa, i.e updates remotely needed to be downloaded what is the best way to do this? The only way I can think of is to ask the server each time the application is launched to download data and compare with local data, however, in theory this could be thousands or hundreds of thousands of updates to download so is not the best idea.

Comment: Of course, alternatively, I can make sure that downloading the data is contextual - only downloading the data when accessing the relevant view controller. For example, when looking at a 'Users View Controller' I download a collection of users and update the local store of users which are not there, and the same for users who are there and shouldn't be